# How do you bind methods to objects in python during runtime?

Tags: python, monkeypatching, setattr

I want to add a method to an object during runtime as thus.

```
class C(object):
  def __init__(self, value)
    self.value = value

obj = C('test')

def f(self):
  print self.value

setattr(obj, 'f', f)
obj.f()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

But it seems that setattr does not bind the method to the object. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Also, I wrote a blog post about this topic in python: https://creatism.wordpress.com/2015/10/26/creating-function-and-class-objects-in-python/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `MethodType` from [types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html) module:

```
import types

obj.f = types.MethodType(f, obj)    
obj.f()
```

But are you really need this? Look for decorators (for example), it's more elegant way to add needed functionality to class.

Comment: I'm designing a factory function that generates objects based on what kind of parameter is supplied. So, if I want to define a horse, I just call AnimalFactory(properties=[HasFourLegs, CanRun]). I forgot what this paradigm is called.

Answer (score 1):

There is way, that I discovered, using the locals() binding space and the exec() command. First, you have to create a function object from the exec() builtin and extract it:

```
def make_function(name, parameter, commands):
    func = 'def {name}({parameter}):'.format(name=name,     parameter=parameter)
    for line in commands:
        func += '\n\t' + line
    exec(func)
    return locals()[name]

>>> func = make_function('help', 'pay', ['pay+=2', 'pay*=5', 'credit = pay//3', 'return credit'])
>>> func(8)
16
```

Then, you need another function that creates an instance object using the **dict** attribute. The **dict** of an object is like it's internal dictionary of attributes that can be accessed via the . commands, it makes a python object similar to a javascript object.

```
def create_object(names, values):
    assert len(names) == len(values)
    exec('class one: pass')
    obj = locals()['one']()
    for i in range(len(names)):
       obj.__dict__[names[i]] = values[i]
    return obj

>>> func = make_function('help', 'pay', ['pay+=2', 'pay*=5', 'credit = pay//3', 'return credit'])
>>> test_obj = create_object(['help', 'interest', 'message'], [func, 0.5, 'please pay by thursday.'])
>>> test_obj.help(7)
15
>>> test_obj.interest
0.5
>>> test_obj.message
'please pay by thursday.'
```

This function essentially zips to separate lists together, to create a set of attributes for your instance object.

Comment: using locals() looks like an overkill though... I guess there really is no simple way such as setattr(obj, 'f', classmethod(f)) (does not work for instantiated object, works for classes).

Comment: you could try using obj.__dict__['f'] = classmethod(f)

Answer (score 1):

In fact, `seattr` will not to pass self/object to method being attached.
So what you could to do is something like this:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

obj = C('some thing')


def make_method(_object, *args, **kwargs):
    def f(self=_object):
        print self.value
    return f

setattr(obj, 'f', make_method(obj))
obj.f()
```

It works because `f()` has access to `make_method()` scope, as it is a inner/nested/closure function.

Comment: I think may not work for more complex functions that have parameters, especially *args.

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me!  Thank you so much!